# Get the list of all instance of enum type and iterate in view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, enums

I have a enum as below :

```
    public static enum Status {
    UNKNOWN(0, "Unknown"), AVAILABLE(1, "Available"), ISSUED(2, "Issued"), RETURNED(
            3, "Returned"), DAMAGED(4, "Damaged"), LOST(5, "Lost"), UNDER_REPAIR(
            6, "Under Repair");

    private int id;
    private String description;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    private Status(Integer id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

How can I get a list of all enum instances and iterate in view some thing like below (I use angular js to iterate in below code):

```
            <select name="status" ng-model="ticket.status">
                <option value="">----Select----</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="s in statusList" value ={{s.id}}>{{s.description}}</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Why you tagged `spring` and `spring-mvc`?

Comment: Thought there are any Utils in Spring to do that work. Any way I am removing it.

Answer (score 2):

All possible enum values can be accessed:

```
Status.values()
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

If you want to access these in angular, you should make a controller in Java and get those values via an http request from angular.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your angularJS code will not work. You're iteration part (s in status) needs to look into an array of JavaScript objects (namely status should be an array of such objects). In your case, from the code listed, status seems to refer to the object associated with the select element, which is not an array of anything. 
In order to do what you want to do:

- return the list of enum values to Javascript, as response to a REST call (using $resource("").query()). On the server-side, you need to develop a REST service (or a Spring controller) that will return the array of enum values. The actual array is easy to obtain, just call Status.values()).
- your JSON array will look like [{"id:"0","description":"Unknown"},{...}]
- get the result from $resource() call in AngularJS and store it in your model (into something like $scope.statuses)
- iterate on this in your code: (s in $scope.statuses).

Comment: Edited the question to make the code more clear to understand. its now ng-repeat="s in statusList"

Comment: Status.values() returns the list of enums as required but in view I receive it in the below format: ["UNKNOWN", "AVAILABLE", "ISSUED".....

Comment: how can I get  JSON array looking like  [{"id:"0","description":"Unknown"},{...}]

Comment: I use Spring controller and my code is like : model.put("statusList", Status.values());

Comment: Instead of returning a model (HashMap<String, Object>) your method from the controller can return directly Status[] or List<Status>